# Issue finding roots in a polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I am trying to find the roots of the polynomial `(-2 + x)^3 (-2 + x^2) (-4 + x^3) (4 + 2 x^2 + x^4) (-8 - 8 x - 2 x^2 + x^3 + x^4)` .
I am using the command

```
Roots[(-2 + x)^3 (-2 + x^2) (-4 + x^3) (4 + 2 x^2 + x^4) (-8 - 8 x - 
2 x^2 + x^3 + x^4)==0,x]
```

However, this is giving, as one

> (-2 + x)^3 (-2 + x^2) (-4 + x^3) (4 + 2 x^2 + x^4) (-8 - 8 x - 2 x^2 +
>       x^3 + x^4)

Does anyone know why this is happening and if there is a way to get all the roots of the given polynomial?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The function returns the roots.  What output do you get and what are you expecting to get instead?  What do you mean by "However, this is giving, as one"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `Solve` or `NSolve`

```
sol = x/.NSolve[(-2 + x)^3 (-2 + x^2) (-4 + x^3) (4 + 2 x^2 + x^4) (-8 - 8 x - 
 2 x^2 + x^3 + x^4) == 0, x]
```

> {-1.41421, -1.34768, -0.940763 - 1.33336 I, -0.940763 + 
>     1.33336 I, -0.793701 - 1.37473 I, -0.793701 + 
>     1.37473 I, -0.707107 - 1.22474 I, -0.707107 + 1.22474 I, 
>    0.707107 - 1.22474 I, 
>    0.707107 + 1.22474 I, 1.41421, 1.5874, 2., 2., 2., 2.22921}

If you want only `Real` roots,

```
sol = x/.NSolve[(-2 + x)^3 (-2 + x^2) (-4 + x^3) (4 + 2 x^2 + x^4) (-8 - 8 x - 
 2 x^2 + x^3 + x^4) == 0, x, Reals]
```

> {-1.41421, -1.34768, 1.41421, 1.5874, 2., 2., 2., 2.22921}

Comment: Thanks so much! Sorry for bothering, but is there a way to get a list of only the roots? I want to take only take the roots of one of the factors? The whole product I asked for is given to me by a written program, but I am just interested in the roots of the polynomial with the biggest root. Is that possible?

Comment: As you can see, `sol` contains all the roots. If you want to find the biggest one use `Max[sol]`. It works only for real roots. Then you can have a `{poly,Max[sol]}` array, from which you can determine the polynomial with largest root and all its roots.

Comment: @user41139 Maybe `FactorList` would be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I think you still have to use `Solve`/`Nsolve` to find the roots of the factors. Better cut the middleman :)

Comment: In my read of the OP's comment, two things are needed, to get the roots and to group them according to the factor, so that the factor with the largest roots may be selected. So you'll need both the factors and the roots. It's not clear there's a middleman here. (In my read, the OP means factor when saying "the polynomial," which is confusing.)

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the ordering of polynomial roots by `Root` to find the maximum real root. The first root is always the minimum real root, so change the sign of the variable and the result.

```
maxRealRoot[f_] := -Root[f[-#] &, 1]
```

Now make your polynomial a function:

```
poly[x_] = (-2 + x)^3 (-2 + x^2) (-4 + x^3) (4 + 2 x^2 + x^4) (-8 - 
8 x - 2 x^2 + x^3 + x^4)
```

Get an exact algebraic result:

```
maxRealRoot[poly]
(* -Root[-8 + 8 #1 - 2 #1^2 - #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1] *)
```

Convert to an approximate numerical result:

```
%//N
(* 2.22921 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

When I evaluate

```
Roots[
  (-2 + x)^3 (-2 + x^2) (-4 + x^3) (4 + 2 x^2 + x^4) (-8 - 8 x - 2 x^2 + x^3 + x^4) 
    == 0, x] // N
```

I get

[image: result]

which seems to me to be a reasonable  result. So I would recommend restarting Mathematica and trying again.